# xQuery distinct-value sum issue

Tags: xquery

I need to sum up the average price of specific product categories, currently i have managed to merge the same category types and count them, now i need to sum up all the prices from the different categories (currently i have selected all prices in my query)

for example: if there are 5 Products of Category A i need to select those 5 prices and sum them up.

**Query**:

```
let $hk := doc('http://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1')/handelskette/produkte/produkt

for $x in distinct-values($hk/kategorie)
let $c := count($hk[kategorie eq $x])
let $a:= sum($hk/ekPreis)

return <kategorie kname="{$x}">
<anzahl>{$c}</anzahl>
<avgEkPreis>{$a div $c}</avgEkPreis>
</kategorie>
```

**XML**:

```
<handelskette>
    <produkte>
        <produkt ean="0-666-4567-2-22">
            <bezeichnung>Autoschampoo</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Pflege</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>35</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>69</listPreis>
        </produkt>
        <produkt ean="0-777-4997-2-43">
            <bezeichnung>Glanzpolitur</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Pflege</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>70</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>119</listPreis>
        </produkt>
        <produkt ean="1-4444-652-8-88">
            <bezeichnung>CD-Wechsler</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Audio</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>2345</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>3999</listPreis>
        </produkt>
    </produkte>  
</handelskette>
```

I would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply use**:

```
sum(for $vCat in distinct-values(/*/*/*/kategorie),
        $vCount in count(/*/*/produkt[kategorie eq $vCat])
     return
        sum(/*/*/produkt[kategorie eq $vCat]/ekPreis/xs:double(.)) div $vCount
    )
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression (and also a XQuery) is evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<handelskette>
    <produkte>
        <produkt ean="0-666-4567-2-22">
            <bezeichnung>Autoschampoo</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Pflege</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>35</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>69</listPreis>
        </produkt>
        <produkt ean="0-777-4997-2-43">
            <bezeichnung>Glanzpolitur</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Pflege</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>70</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>119</listPreis>
        </produkt>
        <produkt ean="1-4444-652-8-88">
            <bezeichnung>CD-Wechsler</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Audio</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>2345</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>3999</listPreis>
        </produkt>
    </produkte>
</handelskette>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the sum of the average prices for each category) is produced:**

```
2397.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't explain it exactly the right way, my english isn't so good^^. i meant that i needed each category for its own summed up, but thanks to you i got it done with parts of your posted syntax.

here is my query now - if someone has a similar issue:

```
let $hk := doc('http://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1')/handelskette/produkte/produkt

for $x in distinct-values($hk/kategorie)
let $c := count($hk[kategorie eq $x])
let $a:= sum($hk[kategorie eq $x]/ekPreis)

return <kategorie kname="{$x}">
<anzahl>{$c}</anzahl>
<avgEkPreis>{$a div $c}</avgEkPreis>
</kategorie>
```

Thank you very much and have a nice week!

Answer (score 0):

Given your processor handles XQuery 3.0 you might give `group by` a try for improved readability:

```
for $produkt  in  doc('http://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1')/handelskette/produkte/produkt
  group by $kname := $produkt/kategorie
  let $anzahl     := count($produkt)
  let $avg_ek     := sum($produkt/ekPreis) div $anzahl
return
<kategorie kname="{ $kname }">
  <anzahl>{ $anzahl }</anzahl>
  <avgEkPreis>{ $avg_ek }</avgEkPreis>
</kategorie>
```